# Is there a one-liner to put a string in a list an amount of times that's specified in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary that contains string, integer pairs like this:

```py
dict = {
    'a': 2,
    'b': 0,
    'c': 3
}
```

I need to generate the following list from it:

```py
list = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Now, I can do this with a normal function quite easily:

```py
def foo(dict):
    list = []
    for key, value in dict:
        for n in range(value):
            list.append(key)
    return list
```

However, I'd prefer to solve this with a one-liner, or at least shorten the function to remove the double for loop, if possible. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `list.append()` calls can be turned into a list comprehension, quite trivially:

```
[key for key, value in d.items() for _ in range(value)]
```

Note that I used the name `d` for the dictionary, not `dict`.

You can produce the sequence lazily by using the [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, starmap

chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, d.items()))
```

The [`itertools.starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) function calls `repeat(key, value)` repeatedly, producing [`itertools.repeat()` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat), and [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) takes each `repeat()` object and flattens what these produce as a single sequence.

This also happens to be the implementation that [`Counter.elements()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements) uses, so you could also use a `Counter` object:

```
Counter(d).elements()
```

but take into account that this then has to create a copy of your input dictionary first. It may be that you should be using a `Counter` for the rest of your code, too, of course.

Demo of these implementations:

```
>>> [key for key, value in d.items() for _ in range(value)]
['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c']
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat, starmap
>>> it = chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, d.items()))
>>> list(it)
['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> it = Counter(d).elements()
>>> list(it)
['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

I used `list()` to collect all elements from the iterator versions into a new list in one step.

Comment: Thanks, it looks exactly like what I was looking for, I couldn't get it to work because I switched the for loops around. Thank you!

Comment: @n0stalghia: remember: list comprehensions list loops in nesting order, from left to right. `for key, value in d.items()` is the outermost loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use `collections.Counter`. It provides an `elements` method which produces all the elements of a `Counter` when viewed as a multiset of elements.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = dict(a=2, b=0, c=3)  # The multiset {'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c'}
>>> list(Counter(d).elements())
['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

The standard warnings about the order in which `d` (and subsequently `Counter(d)`) yields its keys applies.

Comment: Thanks, never heard of collections.Counter before. I will use this method since it's twice as fast as a list comprehension on a sample size of a dict with 5 keys, and all values being 100000.

Comment: @n0stalghia how did you test that? Did you iterate over all values that `Counter().elements()` produces? Or did you only time creating the iterable? The `chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, d.items())` expression in my answer is also how `.elements()` is implemented; use that to avoid creating a copy of the dictionary into a `Counter`.

Comment: I tested this with timeit. The code I used was the following: 
```d = {'test1': 100000, 'test2': 100000, 'test3': 100000, 'test4': 100000, 'test5': 100000}

foo1 = [key for key, value in d.items() for _ in range(value)] foo2 = list(Counter(d).elements())```. No function, just timed how fast it is at creating the variables foo1/foo2 (I did two separate tests, obviously)